# How to migrate react application on server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, razzle

I am currently having a client side react application, which is using redux and saga patterns but does not have security implemented.
Also there is a server side nodejs application, which has security implemented.

So i want my application to migrate and merge at server side so that it can take advantage of the security implementation and server side rendering.

There are various frameworks available such as Razzle, NextJS etc. but not sure which one should I choose for migrating to server side.
Or should I migrate without making use of any framework.

What should be the best approach?

Comment: I've heard good things about NextJS. 
Please try the POC of migration first. Also I think the biggest change would be react-router. Since in NextJS it uses it's router which is server side.

Comment: I'm a FE developer and our app is in the same boat. I'm aware that my snr full-stack dev is using NextJS to migrate the server side which he thinks is best suited for the job.